# jupyter notebook InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

everyone. I am going to run mask RCNN recently. After installing CUDA + cudnn + tensorflowgpu for win10, I found that pycharm can run the program, but in Anaconda Jupiter notebook, an error was reported internalerror: cudagetdevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version. I checked my CUDA toolkit and other versions and found no problem.

graphics card NVIDIA GTX950M
graphics driver 442.19
CUDA 9.0
Cudnn 7
tensorflow-gpu 1.9.0
I suspect it's Anaconda's environmental problem, and I find CUDA's version a bit confusing[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yKhg.png)

I hope someone can help me. I really like notebook

Comment: Either your conda installation has a different CUDA toolkit version or some environment settings and path are not getting propagated correctly.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. My CONDA has installed the same version of CUDA toolkit as the computer graphics card. My computer has installed cudnn7.0.5, but the anaconda official website does not support this version, so I have installed a 7.5 version. Is that the reason for this problem?